# How to set child elements to inline when parent container has position absolute

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with `position: absolute` centred in its parent element.

I need the `position: absolute` `div` child elements to be inline.

I tried `float: left` and `display: inline-block` but somehow they don't get inline after a certain width.

How to solve this?

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid blue; 
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

em, ul, ul {
  float: left;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <em><img src="https://placehold.co/40x40"/></em>
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>En</li>
      <li>Pt</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove floats and make all items display: inline, and reset margin padding on ul.

Comment: Still not what I expect. When the width of the window is decreased the child elements start to go to another line even if the is right and left space outside of the parent. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does it have to be position: absolute? Flex box could be used to center the content.

Comment: It does not need to be absolute. I just need the child element to be over an image which is full width.